# Regular Expressions (RegEx) - One String Variable length

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My application receives one barcode where its length is variable. It could be 5, 9, 12 or 14. I'm trying to use something like this:  `\w{14}|\w{12}|\w{9}|\w{5}`

That regular expression is not correct. Is there any regular expression for different lengths?
or What is the right way to combine different regular expressions?

Note: The reason why I'm using regular expressions is a long story.

Comment: "*That regular expression is not correct*," what's wrong with it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and why is your solution not working?

Comment: A problem of boundaries? Try: `^\w{14}|\w{12}|\w{9}|\w{5}$`.

Comment: Prag, that will either look for something at the beginning with 14 characters, something with 12 or 9 characters, or something at the end with 5 characters.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\b(\w{14}|\w{12}|\w{9}|\w{5})\b
```

[image: Regular expression image]

It will match all the words within your string that are either 14, 12, 9, or 5 characters long. You can then check these matches. See a string that contains several matches and non-matches here: http://www.debuggex.com/r/V9T8nHp7ep6yuJow

If you are only hoping to check that the entire string is a single match, use this (to check that it both starts and ends with one of your options):

```
^(\w{14}|\w{12}|\w{9}|\w{5})$
```

Also, all the barcodes I've seen consist only of numbers, is this is the case for you as well... you should replace all the `\w` with `\d` which is the same as `[0-9]`

Comment: This could fail if there is a space in the string.  Ex: "abc 12345" might 'match', but I doubt that's what the original poster intended.

Comment: Assuming the string you get is the entire bar code I suggest you use the ^$ method as this method will match "   djd 12345  ,,," as the 12345 is 5 digits and would match \w{5} and is within a word boundary.

Comment: Yes, 12345 would be a match in the string. The user could look through the matches within the test string - as in the example in the link above. I suppose I'm not sure exactly how the user intends to implement the regex - which might change the requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you wanted this:

```
"^(\w{14}|\w{12}|\w{9}|\w{5})$"
```

Notice the grouping of the different length options, surrounded by beginning and ending of string indicators.  Without those, anything matches if `\w{5}` exists somewhere in the string.